# changing quotation margins temporarily

Tags: indentation, quoting

I wish to change the margins of the `quote` environment, but just for a one-off occasion.  I don't wish to change the `quote` environment throughout the document.

I tried to do the following, but it doesn't work.[image].

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
This is a normal paragraph. This is a normal paragraph. 
This is a normal paragraph. This is a normal paragraph. This is a normal paragraph. 

\begin{quote}
This is a quote, normally with margins. This is a quote, normally with margins. 
This is a quote, normally with margins. This is a quote, normally with margins. 
\end{quote}

\begin{quote}
\setlength{\leftmargin}{0.1in}
\setlength{\rightmargin}{0.1in}
This other quote needs slimmer margins. This other quote needs slimmer margins. 
This other quote needs slimmer margins. This other quote needs slimmer margins. 
\end{quote}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should make the change outside the quote environment.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
This is a normal paragraph. This is a normal paragraph.
This is a normal paragraph. This is a normal paragraph. This is a normal paragraph.

\begin{quote}
This is a quote, normally with margins. This is a quote, normally with margins.
This is a quote, normally with margins. This is a quote, normally with margins.
\end{quote}

\begingroup
\addtolength\leftmargini{0.1in}
\begin{quote}
This other quote needs slimmer margins. This other quote needs slimmer margins.
This other quote needs slimmer margins. This other quote needs slimmer margins.
\end{quote}
\endgroup

\begin{quote}
This is a quote, normally with margins. This is a quote, normally with margins.
This is a quote, normally with margins. This is a quote, normally with margins.
\end{quote}

\end{document}
```

[image]

(You could also use two quote environments)

Comment: Great.  Can I make temporary changes within the same quote environment?  For example, one `\begin{quote}` but multiple paragraphs and margins?

Comment: You can nest list environments and you could e.g. use the addmargin enviroment from the KOMA-classes. But why would you want a lot of different margins? It will certainly not look good.

Comment: my question is theoretical.  I know it looks bad, but I want to understand how TeX thinks about this issue: whether margins are bound to environments or bound to paragraphs.

Comment: Depends. With `\parshape` you change one paragraph, With `\leftskip =3cm` you would change all margins of the environment -- if nothing interferes (which can happen easily as a lot of environments and commands have their own idea about margins).